# How to search the author of any function or variable in the git project?

Tags: git, project

How to search the author of any function or variable in the git project?  I am curious when I find some functions or variables and I want to find who created these things. Are there any methods to track the author name and creation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Brian's answer, `git blame` will tell you the most recent committer / commit to modify a line, but if you want to track that line all the way back in history, you want the "pickaxe search":

```
-S<string>
Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of <string>. Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff output; see
the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7) for more details.
```

Suppose you wanted to find the entire history of the string `methodFoo` in file `TroublingClass`. You could use a `git log` command like the following:

```
git log -S"methodFoo" -- TroublingClass
```

The `-S` flag just doesn't get the attention it deserves. It's enormously useful when attributing fault or investigating bug histories.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems that the string should not be too complex, otherwise it will return no results.

Comment: for instance: the string "update(frame_t frameNumber)" cannot.

Comment: You might need to escape some characters. Try escaping the `\(` and if that doesn't work, use ' marks instead of ".

Answer (score 2):

`git blame` will identify who last modified *each line* in a file/revision.